# Método ejecutado en eventos tarda en ejecutarse c#

Tags: c#

Tengo un **método** que cuando es ejecutado en unos checkboxs funciona a la perfección pero cuando los ejecuto a través de los eventos del **combobox(SelectedIndexChanged)** y de un **textbox(KeyPress)** la primera vez se ejecuta sin problema, sin embargo la segundo tarda como **30 segundos en cargar y consume más de 3GB de RAM**.

```
//El metodo en cuestión es este:
public void actualizarDatos()
        {
            textBox2.Clear();
            string delimitador = (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            string contenido = textBox1.Text;  
            contenido = contenido.Trim();
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                while(contenido.Contains("  "))
                {
                    contenido = contenido.Replace("  ", " ");
                }     
            }
            if (checkBox2.Checked)
            {
                contenido = Regex.Replace(contenido, "[0-9]", "");
            }
            foreach (var listboxItem in listBox1.Items)
            {
               contenido = contenido.Replace(listboxItem.ToString(),"");
            }
            string[] contenidoSplited = new string[contenido.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < contenido.Length; i++)
            {
                contenidoSplited[i] = contenido[i].ToString();
                if (contenido[i] == Convert.ToChar(delimitador))
                {
                    contenidoSplited[i] = "\r\n";
                }
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < contenidoSplited.Length; i++)
            {
                textBox2.Text += contenidoSplited[i];
            }
            text = textBox1.Text;
            result = textBox2.Text;
        }
```

Y los eventos que lo ejecutan son estos:

```
//funciona sin ningún tipo de problema y las veces que sean.
private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {        
            actualizarDatos();
        }
//Los que funcionan la primera vez, y la segunda tardan y consumen...

private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            actualizarDatos();
        }
//----------------------------------------------------------------
private void TextBox3_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                string filtro = textBox3.Text;
                textBox3.Clear();
                if (filtro != "" && filtro != " ")
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(filtro);
                    actualizarDatos();
                }
            }
        }
```

No he trabajo con eventos pero no entiendo este comportamiento cualquier ayuda me vendría muy bien!

Si puede ayudar....
https://youtu.be/Bb-QZwvz7Jo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La verdad es que no acabo de entender el comportamiento del método `.Text` de los elementos `textBox` con propiedad `multiline`.

No obstante, por detrás están formados por `arrays` de `strings`, que son una línea cada uno. Así y reemplazando el método e interactuando directamente con el `array` de líneas parece no dar problemas.

```
public void actualizarDatos()
{
    textBox2.Lines = new string[0]; // Sustituyo el método clear
    string delimitador = (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

    // Equivalente a .Text
    string contenido = "";
    foreach (string line in textBox1.Lines)
        contenido += line + "\n");

    text = contenido;
    contenido = contenido.Trim();
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
        while(contenido.Contains("  "))
            contenido = contenido.Replace("  ", " ");

    if (checkBox2.Checked)
        contenido = Regex.Replace(contenido, "[0-9]", "");

    foreach (var listboxItem in listBox1.Items)
        contenido = contenido.Replace(listboxItem.ToString(),"");

    // Podemos cambiar a array de chars, ya que no es necesario utilizar
    // retorno de carro con el método split, obligatorio al reemplazar el
    // método text
    char[] contenidosplitted = new char[contenido.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < contenido.Length; i++)
    {
        contenidosplitted[i] = contenido[i];
        if (contenido[i] == delimitador[0])
            contenidosplitted[i] = '\n';
    }

    contenido = "";
    foreach(char character in contenidosplitted)
        contenido += character;

    result = contenido;
    textBox2.Lines = contenido.Split('\n');
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias maduranma! Me funciona perfectamente ahora:)